# How can I contain a created slickgrid within a div tag?

Tags: jquery, css, slickgrid

Currently I am attempting to create a page that could hold multiple SlickGrids.  I don't want the grids to become too compressed, so if multiple grids are too large for the page, I'd simply like to be able to scroll through them.  However, I don't want to have to scroll the entire page, as there is information at the top of the page I'd like to remain visible.

What I was hoping to be able to do is have one `div` that will contain all the grids and if the grids extend past the bottom of that element I will be able to scroll.  However, when I test this, SlickGrid's generation seems to force the grid to overflow on top of the div, completely ignoring its boundaries!

The test code is as follows (except for generating the data which comes from an AJAX call).  I am not changing the sizes of either the grid or the containing element.

HTML:

```
<div style='height:500px; width: 1200px; overflow:hidden !important; border:1px solid red; z-index:500000; margin-left:20px;' id='showTable'>
    <div id="myGrid" style="width: 1200px; height: 700px;"></div>
</div>
```

JavaScript Call:

```
grid = new Slick.Grid("#myGrid", data, columns, options);
grid.setSelectionModel(new Slick.RowSelectionModel());
```

So far I've tried using a ul instead of the div as the containing element and also appending the grid back into the containing element - `$("#showTable").append($("#myGrid"));` - after completely loading the grid.

The result is that the grid just sits on top of the outer element (the red is the border of the element I would like it to be contained in, and you can see a button I have as well.  The columns are intentionally obscured):

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABi2K.png]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABi2K.png

Any insights?

Answer (score 1):

```
<div style='height:500px; width: 1200px; overflow:hidden !important; border:1px solid red; z-index:500000; margin-left:20px;' id='showTable'>
    <div id="myGrid" style="width: 1200px; height: 700px;"></div>
</div>
```

I think your #myGrid div exceeds the height of the outer div that's why it looks like it's ignoring its boundaries.

You could define the absolute height&width of the grids so that it would fit inside your outer div element.

Could also define overflow property as scroll instead of hidden

```
overflow:scroll
```

This would make the inner div hidden but still scrollable

To avoid having 2 scrolls (div scroll, and grid scroll) you could remove the grid scroll by specifying autoHeight property as true:

```
  var options = {
      enableCellNavigation: true,
      enableColumnReorder: false,
      autoHeight: true,
  };
```

You can now contain 2 or more grids inside your outer div:

```
  <div id="showTable" style="overflow:auto;width:600px;height:300px;border:1px solid red">
      <div id="myGrid" style="width:600px;height:500px;"></div>
      <div id="myGrid2" style="width:600px;height:500px;"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: This makes sense, but my intention was that, if the grid does extend beyond the border of that outer div, it is hidden instead of overflowing. It could be that I'm making a fundamental error with regards to the CSS though.

Comment: Hi, added some more suggestion that might fit what you want to achieve